# Directorist WordPress Plugin - Add CUSTOM BADGE

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've been using this plugin for a couple of days now and I'm doing really well but unfortunately I don't have the option to add a custom badge.
However, I saw on their site that some case studies have modified the plugin programmatically to be able to add custom badges.
What do you think the simplest solution would be?
I leave you all the documentation here.
https://directorist.com/documentation/directorist/#23
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To this date you still cannot add a custom Badge, but the simplest solution would be to change the label of one of the badges you don't use to become the one you need.

You can alter it's background color in the *Color* option in the *Personalization* screen in *Settings*.